# Why css float does not work as expected

Tags: css

I have created 2 div one with float: left and one with float : right, each with 50% column width. Still they don't flow as expected. The second float not just on the right side of the first div but below the first div. Float doesn't behave according to the rule. So what rule am I missing here ?

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .column {
                width: 50%;
            }
            div.right {
                float: right;
            }
            }
            div.left {
                float: left;    
            }

            img {
              float: right;
              margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class='left column'>
        <img src="css-float.png">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
    </div>

    <div class='right column'>
        <img src="css-float.png">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is invalid, so stopping the rest of your stylesheet loading.

See here:

```
        div.right {
            float: right;
        }
        }
```

You are closing the rule twice, remove the second closing bracket

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/9KG6Y/)

```
        .column {
            width: 49%;
        }

        div.left, div.right {
            float: left;  
            border-right: 1px solid;
        }
```

Reduce your width. You need side by side, So you add float left since both are under same container.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/BeyondNero/5HLHV/)

```
.column {
                width: 50%;
            }
            div.right {
                float: right;
            }

            div.left {
                float: left;    
            }

            img {
              float: right;
                     padding-right: 15px;
              margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
```